# What does "Universal character name conversion" mean in C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compilation

C++98 apparently has this as one of the standards for compilation phases. What does it mean and why is it executed initially?

Comment: perhaps mark the answer as correct?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A universal character name looks like `\uFFFD` or `\U0010FFFD`. It's a method of writing a character in your source code where the source code encoding does not include that character.

C++ specifies that characters not in the basic source character set be transformed into universal character names in the first phase of translation. The reason for this is so that universal character names and characters which are not in the basic source character set but which are in the source character set get treated identically.

The *as-if* rule means that an implementation is not actually required to do this universal character name translation, as long as it treats extended characters written as universal character names identically with extended characters that appear literally in the source.

Comment: Are they all unicode encoded characters? So Chinese characters are for example converted to unicodefirst?

Comment: Yes, Universal character names use Unicode short names (the number Unicode associates with each character). For example, Unicode assigns the character '⻰' the short name U+2EF0 and so the universal character name for this character would be `\u2EF0` or `\U00002EF0`

Comment: So I wrote a program to convert a C++ source file into nothing but universal character names. G++ first gave a bunch of errors about using universal characters in identifiers, and then finished with `error: '#include <stdio.h>\012int main() {\012\011printf("Hello, world!\n");\012\011return 0;\012}\012' does not name a type`. So I either there *is* a difference between universal character names and the actual characters they represent, or there's a bug in GNU C++.

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million There is one difference: UCNs representing characters in the basic source character set are not allowed to appear outside character and string literals.